# QML application and screen flickering

Tags: qml, fullscreen

I use windows 10 (updated), Python 3.5 and IDE PyCharm (full updated).

My problem: The screen has flickering when I click on the button.

The button was used to open File dialog window. Application window is showed from the python side via showFullscreen option (code is below).

How can I solve this problem.

MktLabelButton.qml

```
    import QtQuick 2.7

 Item {
    id: mktLabelButton
    x: 10
    y: 10
    width: 48
    height: 48

    signal buttonClicked()

    property alias imageSource : mktLabelButtonIcon.source
    property alias imageLabel  : mktLabelButtonText.text

    Image{
        id: mktLabelButtonIcon
        source: imageSource
        sourceSize.height: mktLabelButton.height
        sourceSize.width: mktLabelButton.width
        scale: mktLabelButtonMouseArea.containsMouse ? 1.2 : 0.85
        Behavior on scale {
            ScaleAnimator {duration: 100}
        }
    }

    Text{
        id: mktLabelButtonText
        font.bold: true
        text: imageLabel
        x: (mktLabelButton.width - contentWidth) / 2
        y: mktLabelButton.height + 5
        color: mktLabelButtonMouseArea.containsMouse ? "yellow":"white"
        Behavior on color {
            ColorAnimation {duration: 100}
        }
    }

    MouseArea{
        id: mktLabelButtonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: mktLabelButtonIcon
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: buttonClicked()
    }
}
```

MainForm.py

```
    import sys
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

class MainForm:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.__parent = parent
        self.__openButton = parent.findChild(QObject, "openButton")
        self.__openButton.buttonClicked.connect(self.openButtonClicked)

    def openButtonClicked(self):
        fd = self.__parent.findChild(QObject, "mktFileDialog")
        fd.setProperty("show", "true")



    def show(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appQueue = QApplication([])
    appEngine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    appEngine.load(QUrl("file:///E:/QML/01012017/Verison1/qml/mainform/mainform.qml"))
    appWindow = appEngine.rootObjects()[0]
    appWindow.showFullScreen()
    mf = MainForm(appWindow)
    sys.exit(appQueue.exec_())
```

MktFileDialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Item {
    id: mktFileDialog
    objectName: "mktFileDialogPY"

    property alias show: mktFileDialogMain.visible

    FileDialog{
        id: mktFileDialogMain
        title: "Comet görüntüleri"
        visible: show
    }
}
```

mainform.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    color: "black"

    MktLabelButton{
        objectName: "openButton"
        x:50
        y:50
        imageSource: "img/open.png"
        imageLabel: "Open"
    }

    MktFileDialog{
        objectName: "mktFileDialog"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it flick if you remove the animation effects?

Comment: Yes, flickering continues.

Comment: A quick search on google reveals Windows platform has some flickering issues. So, test it on Linux, if it does flick, then its your App, if it does not then it is your Windows OS and nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: This problem was appeared when I want to run application via full screen mode. Do I need to change operating system ? Could be a solution without changing operating system.